# Web3Auth Login with Gmail Stopped Working in My DApp

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core, web3auth

I've implemented Web3Auth in my decentralized application (DApp) to enable users to log in using Twitter and Gmail. This setup was working smoothly up until about a week ago when it suddenly stopped functioning. Users are no longer able to log in, and it seems the issue lies within the SDK. Users can select their gmail account but when it comes to the next step it throws error.

Here's a snippet of the code where the error occurs:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { broadcastChannelOptions, PopupData } from "@toruslabs/base-controllers";
import { BroadcastChannel } from "@toruslabs/broadcast-channel";
import { safeatob } from "@toruslabs/openlogin-utils";
import { Loader } from "@toruslabs/vue-components/Loader";
import log from "loglevel";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

import OpenLoginFactory from "../handlers/Auth/OpenLoginFactory";
import type { OpenLoginPopupResponse } from "../utils/interfaces";
import { setTheme } from "../utils/utils";

async function endLogin() {
  try {
    const { hash } = useRoute();
    const hashParams = new URLSearchParams(hash.slice(1));
    const error = hashParams.get("error");

    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }

    const openLoginInstance = await OpenLoginFactory.getInstance();
    const openLoginState = openLoginInstance.state;
    const { privKey, sessionId } = openLoginState;

    if (!privKey) {
      throw new Error("Login unsuccessful");
    }
    const userInfo = openLoginInstance.getUserInfo();
    const { appState } = userInfo;
    if (!appState) {
      throw new Error("Login unsuccessful");
    }
    const parsedAppState = JSON.parse(safeatob(decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(appState as string))));
    const { instanceId } = parsedAppState;

    const bc = new BroadcastChannel(instanceId, broadcastChannelOptions);
    await bc.postMessage({
      data: {
        sessionId,
      },
    } as PopupData<OpenLoginPopupResponse>);
  } catch (error) {
    log.error(error);
    // TODO: Display error to user and show crisp chat
  }
}

setTheme();
endLogin();
</script>
```

The error I'm encountering is thrown by the line: `throw new Error("Login unsuccessful");`. This suggests that the login process fails before it can retrieve a private key or user information, which is essential for the authentication process.

Given this was working previously, I haven't made any changes to my code or the way I'm using the SDK, so I suspect the issue might be related to an update in the SDK or an external dependency.

Has anyone else experienced similar issues with Web3Auth? I'm looking for any insights or solutions that could help resolve this issue. Your assistance would be greatly appreciated as it's critical for the operation of my DApp.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Web3Auth SDK](https://web3auth.io/docs/sdk) instead of Torus Open Login as it has been [deprecated](https://docs.tor.us/deprecated/) in favor of the former.

I see that you used `safe-core` and `safe-core-sdk` tags for your questions, however I don't see any Safe-related code in your snippet. Is it still of interest?

Best, Louis